# Convoluted formula using INDIRECT, ADDRESS and MATCH - is there a better way?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get a MAX of a range that is bound by two 1s in a helper column.

The 1s are a variable number of rows apart.

By way of example, here is a sample of what I'm talking about:

```
1   
0   -1.10%
0   0.00%
1   
0   1.43%
0   1.15%
0   2.12%
0   2.69%
0   1.32%
0   0.86%
0   -0.69%
1
~
[and so on]
```

So, for instance, there are two ranges visible that I'm interested in here -- the range between rows 1 and 4 and the range between rows 4 and 12.

In a third column, wherever there is a 1 in the helper column, I want the MAX of the ranges.

I've managed to cobble together this formula that does the job *(this is copied directly from the spreadsheet so it's in row 122 and the data currently goes to row 16120, the helper column is column E and the column with the values is F)*:

```
=IF(E122=1,MAX(F122:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+MATCH(1,E123:$E$16120,0),COLUMN(F122),4))),"")
```

My basic thinking is to build the bottom of the range by looking for the next 1 down the helper column (using MATCH), add that to the current row (using ROW and COLUMN) wrapped inside an ADDRESS function and then tie it all together using INDIRECT. Finally, it sits inside an IF to only hit the rows with a 1 in the helper column.

Can anyone think of a more elegant, less cumbersome way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a larger dataset, I'd recommend to use `INDEX` instead of `OFFSET`! The latter is volatile, i.e. Excel will recalculate all OFFSET formulas and any dependants every time it does any recalculation. INDEX on the other hand is non-volatile, i.e. only if any of it's predecessors change will Excel recalc the formula.

Therefore, give this formula a try:

```
=IF(E122=1,MAX(F123:INDEX(F123:$F$16120,MATCH(1,E123:$E$16120,0))),"")
```

Comment: +1! Good answer! I know that `OFFSET` is volatile and thought about using `INDEX`, but I don't know about the trick `MAX(F123:INDEX(..))`. Thank you for unexpectedly teaching me!

Comment: Wow - even better. Thanks to all. I knew there had to be an optimum way compared to my crazy solution.

Comment: @simoco: For years, I also used OFFSET in a lot of situations. Took a while to realize that the `:` is actually an operator and one could replace almost any `OFFSET` with `INDEX(...):INDEX(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [OFFSET](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/offset-HP005209208.aspx):

```
=IF(E122=1,MAX(OFFSET(E122,1,1,MATCH(1,E123:$E$16120,0)))-1,"")
```

Comment: Much better. Of course OFFSET works here. For some reason I'd convinced myself it wouldn't and went around it the hard way. Many thanks.

Comment: +1 also a viable way - and perfectly fine (and less of a headache then my answer) in small files.

Comment: Where I had gone conceptually wrong was thinking that INDEX only returned the *value* of a cell. Lesson: read the documentation!